# weird behavior of right-shift key in combination with semicolon or quotemark key

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm having trouble with my Apple bluetooth keyboard for several days after upgrading my system to Lion.  In a weird way, neither right shift+; nor right shift+' is working.  I have no trouble with the left shift key, or the right shift key with any other keys.  Can anybody give me some suggestion to solve this?

Comment: I'm sure you meant "shift" in the posting title :)

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of one key not functioning is that it has been somehow set as the trigger for Text to Speech or Speech Recognition in system preferences/speech.